# ggplot - Boxplot not generating box

Tags: r, ggplot2

So Im working through a stats assignment and ive been asked to create a boxplot and its working grand but its not generating the box itself and im really confused. I have reclassified the value for the boxplot as a numeric, tried clearing the environment and uploading the data again and nothing has worked so far

```
train.df.improve %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x="", y= Improvement)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  ggtitle("Boxplot of Improvement in Squat Weight") + 
  xlab("") + 
  ylab("Improvement in Squat Weight (Kg)") + 
  coord_flip()
```

dput((train.df.improve) gives me the following:

```
structure(list(ID = 1:18, VO2.max_Pre = c(66.4, 70.9, 64.9, 68.6, 
76.7, 75.6, 78.1, 73.1, 74.4, 64.9, 63, 66.6, 64.2, 58.7, 66.4, 
61.9, 62.8, 60.6), VO2.max_Post = c(67.8, 81.7, 70.1, 73, 84.5, 
78.4, 80.5, 76, 78.7, 72.8, 67.3, 71.8, 70.1, 65, 72.4, 66.2, 
69, 64.5), Squat_Pre = c(120L, 120L, 130L, 130L, 110L, 130L, 
140L, 120L, 140L, 100L, 140L, 130L, 150L, 140L, 130L, 160L, 150L, 
100L), Squat_Post = c(140L, 150L, 160L, 160L, 140L, 160L, 170L, 
140L, 170L, 130L, 180L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 150L, 190L, 190L, 130L
), Improvement = c(20L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 20L, 30L, 
30L, 40L, 40L, 20L, 30L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 30L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-18L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you share a sample of your data with `dput(train.df.improve)`?

Comment: Hi, this is what R gives me.

Comment: `geom_boxplot()` is behaving as expected. We can see from `quantile(train.df.improve$Improvement)` that the 25th and 75th percentiles of "Improvement" are both 30, so instead of a box, you get a line.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. However my t.test results are the following: data:  .
t = 19.545, df = 17, p-value = 4.356e-13
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 26.26609 32.62280
sample estimates:
mean of x 
 29.44444 
Which would indicate to me that the box should form around 26.2-32.6?

Comment: No. The confidence interval assumes that the data are normally distributed around their mean. A boxplot is drawn based on the empirical percentiles of the data.

Comment: If you want a box with dimensions corresponding to 26.2 - 32.6, you could define them yourself via `geom_rect()`.  Specify `ymin=26.2, ymax=32.6` and set `xmin` and `xmax` to something like 0.8 and 1.2 to get the box width looking right.  But... as others correctly point out, this is *not* a boxplot.  A boxplot visually represents quartiles and not a confidence interval.  I would suggest using something like `geom_linerange` or `geom_pointrange` as a way to represent your interval here.

Comment: You could use geom_violin() to see some kind of distribution.